# Estimating the mutual information for two signal samples

Tags: matlab, density-function, mutual-information

I have two signals *s1* and *s2*, sampled 170 times each.

```
x = 0.2:0.2:34;
s1 = rand(size(x));
s2 = randn(size(x));
```

The calculation of the MI (mutual information) between two discrete variables requires knowledge of their marginal probability distribution functions and their joint probability distribution.

I am estimating each signal's marginal distribution using this [Kernel Density Estimator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14034-kernel-density-estimator).

```
[~,pdf1,xmesh1,~]=kde(s1);
[~,pdf2,xmesh2,~]=kde(s2);
```

I am estimating the joint pdf using this [2D Kernel Density Estimator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17204-kernel-density-estimation).

```
[~,pdf_joint,X,Y]=kde2d(data);
```

I created a function which takes as input the original signals, their marginal pdfs, and their joint pdf, and computes the Mutual Information.

Unfortunately, I seem to have some hug bug in this function, which I can't figure out. The MI should always be a positive number, but I am getting complex and/or negative numbers!

The function I wrote for computing the MI is shown below.

```
function mi = computeMI(s1, s2, pdf1, xmesh1, pdf2, xmesh2, pdf_joint, X, Y)

N = size(s1, 2);
p_i = zeros(1, N);
p_j = zeros(1, N);

for i=1:N
    p_i(i) = interp1(xmesh1, pdf1, s1(i));
    p_j(i) = interp1(xmesh2, pdf2, s2(i));
end;

mi = 0;

p_ij = zeros(N, N);

for j=1:N
    for i=1:N
        p_ij(i, j) = interp2(X, Y, pdf_joint, s1(i), s2(j));
        delta_mi = p_ij(i,j) * (log2(p_ij(i,j) / (p_i(i) * p_j(j))));
        mi = mi + delta_mi;
    end;
end;
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: May I ask whether there's a reason why you go through all the effort creating a kernel density estimator. Why don't you just create a 2d histogram, estimate the marginals from that, and use it to estimate the MI?

Comment: Just two other things I noticed: (1) I would use log2(p_ij(i,j)) - log2(p_i(i)) - log2(p_j(j)) for numerical stablity, and (2) the estimated joint distribution and the marginals do not need to be consistent (i.e. if you marginalize the joint distribution you might not get the marginal you estimated) since you use two different estimators for it.

Comment: @fabee First of all thank you for your help. (1) Why would you use this equation? I'm confused. This is not the equation that is used for calculating the Mutual Information. Why would it be useful in my case?

Comment: @fabee (2) I did not really understand this comment. Could you perhaps clarify it?

Comment: @fabee With regards to your first comment - I thought that using kernel density estimators would provide a more 'accurate' description of the pdf, since histograms are, after all, sort of a rough approximation. Also, how would you estimate the marginals from the 2D-histogram? The 2D-histogram would only be a product of the marginals if the original samples are in fact independent, which is what I want to show.

Comment: I put my suggestions in an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot immediately see a bug in your program. However, I see I few things that might alter the outcome of our results.

First of all, I would use $\sum_{ij} p_{ij} \left(\log p_{ij} - \log p_i - \log p_j\right)$ instead of $\sum_{ij} p_{ij} \log \frac{p_{ij}}{p_i\cdot p_j}$ for numerical stability. As a general rule, if you have to multiply probabilities, it is better to work in the log-domain.

Second, since you use different kernel density estimators for the marginals and the joint distribution, they might not be consistent. Let $p(x,y)$ be your joint estimate and $q(x)$ the estimate of one of your marginals. Since $q$ is the marginal of the joint distribution it must hold that $\int p(x,y) dy = p(x) = q(x)$. This is not necessarily the case since you used two different estimators.

Another thing that might get you in trouble is that you interpolate. If you interpolate a density, it will most certainly not integrate to one anymore (that, of course, depends on the type of interpolation you use). This means that you don't even use proper densities anymore.

The easiest solution you could just try out is to use a 2d histogram $H_{ij}$. Let $h_{ij}=H_{ij}/\sum_{ij}H_{ij}$ be the normalized histogram. Then you get the marginals via $h_i = \sum_j h_{ij}$ and $h_j = \sum_i h_{ij}$. The mutual information can then be computed via

```
lh1 = log(sum(h,1));
lh2 = log(sum(h,2));
I = sum(sum(h .* bsxfun(@minus,bsxfun(@minus,log(h),lh1),lh2) ));
```

For increasing number of datapoints and smaller bins, this should converge to the correct value. In our case, I would try to use different bin sizes, compute the MI and take a bin size from the region where the value of the MI seems stable. Alternatively, you could use the heuristic by

> Scott, D. W. (1979). On optimal and data-based histograms. Biometrika, 66(3), 605-610. doi:10.1093/biomet/66.3.605

to choose the bin size.

If you really want to use kernel density estimators, I would adapt the approach from above and

1. compute the marginals from the joint estimation
2. not use interpolation. As I understand, the KDE give you the values of the density at arbitrary base points anyway. Better use those.

One final note, while the MI converges to the true MI with the histogram approach, the entropy does not. So if you want to estimate the differential entropy with a histogram approach, you have to correct for the bin size.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you are normalizing the 2D-histogram and using to get the marginals? I haven't managed to this correctly. I've in fact opened up [another question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24568/normalizing-a-2d-histogram-and-getting-the-marginals).

Comment: Hi Rachel, I also answered your other question. For the MI-estimation here you don't need to take into account the bin-width.